# If an edit changes a post's quality score downwards dramatically, do not merge revisions in the grace period

Tags: feature-request, edits, grace-period, quality

[Case in point.](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4654369/revisions) The user found out the solution to his question within 5 minutes of having posted it, and instead of answering his question or deleting it he merely vandalized it.

Thanks to the edit merging feature, his original post is now lost.

I'm not saying the edit should be refused -- merely not merged, for others to review and rollback if necessary.

<sub>In this particular case in point, a comment by the asker in reply to, er, an [answer-that-really-is-a-comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654369/jquery-animate-css-error/4654384#4654384) luckily allowed me to get the question back into shape (it also contains the answer, if anybody is willing to get some free reps).</sub>

Comment: For the archives, according to search engine caches, after editing it said: *Nevermind, I managed to fix it :)* I've left a comment at another post of [the user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/518513/kyle-r) to indicate we don't like that.

Comment: Hmmm, the user is [clearly not convinced](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237800/converted-from-http-to-https-errors-log-in-forms-not-working-php#comment-5953472) that he did anything wrong. :-(

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is a reasonable example.

The question itself was not any good to start with. You can't vandalize crap. I support self-deletion (and it deserved all the downvotes it got) in this case.

It is now deleted.

Comment: I don't know whether or not that question was worth keeping -- I don't know what the question really was to begin with! Did he add code samples? Did he add screenshots? What he tried? Who knows. That's the whole point. (Also, the answer was non trivial in this case.)

Comment: @radp whole scenario is crap, not worth coming up with new rules for. Wake me up when you have a non-crap something *worth* keeping :)